# d3 js circle traveling on a square path animation breathing app

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a breathing app and I need to get the circle to animate around the edge - but in the other direction. Also how would I be able to change the rate of the animation from an external change - if it were to become a react component.

Is there a better way to make this type of animation/visual

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/n87zcdbk/2/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>
      // set up
      const margin = {
        top: 10,
        bottom: 10,
        left: 10,
        right: 10
      };

      const width = 175 - margin.left - margin.right;
      const height = 175 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const svg = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

      const g = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

      // data
      const dataPoints = [{
          "x": 0,
          "y": 50
        },
        {
          "x": 50,
          "y": 50
        }
      ];

      var Gen = d3.area()
        .x((p) => p.x)
        .y0((p) => 0)
        .y1((p) => p.y);

      // scales
      const x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(dataPoints, d => d.x))
        .range([0, width]);

      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(dataPoints, d => d.y))
        .range([height, 0]);

      // line generator
      const line = d3.line()
        .x(d => x(d.x))
        .y(d => y(d.y));

      // add path
      const path = g.append('path')
        .attr('d', Gen(dataPoints))
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('fill', 'none');

      // draw circle at initial location
      const circle = g.append('circle')
        .attr('fill', 'black')
        .attr('r', 5)
        .attr('transform', `translate(${x(dataPoints[0].x)},${y(dataPoints[0].y)})`);




      function newLoop() {
        // animate
        circle.transition()
          .ease(d3.easeLinear)
          .duration(5000)
          .attrTween('transform', translateAlong(path.node()));
      }

      newLoop()
      var duration = 5000;
      setInterval(newLoop, duration);


      // https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868
      function translateAlong(path) {
        const length = path.getTotalLength();
        return function() {
          return function(t) {
            const {
              x,
              y
            } = path.getPointAtLength(t * length);
            return `translate(${x},${y})`;
          }
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it go faster you must modify the times, for example I set both to 1000

```
function newLoop() {
    // animate
    circle.transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(1000)
      .attrTween('transform', translateAlong(path.node()));
  }

  newLoop()
  var duration = 1000;
```

Make the other direction work just change the value of x in the datapoints.
Like below:

```
const dataPoints = [{
      "x": 50,
      "y": 50
    },
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 50
    }
];
```

**Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/SeiryuV/whdp5xfm/9/

Comment: could we have one duration variable like this - https://jsfiddle.net/2dsx73gj/

Comment: Of course.
That will help to keep it more organized.